# Best way to get user input when length is unknown? (C)

Tags: c

Trying to get the user to enter multiple lines of input, but I don't know how long their input will be. I think I would want to use a char pointer array, but why won't the below code work? It compiles fine, I just get unexpected results.

```
char x[] = "";
scanf("%s", x);

char y[] = "";
scanf("%s", y);

printf("You entered: '%s' and '%s'\n", x, y);
```

Is it because of the way i'm initializing `x` and `y`?

Comment: Yes, it is.  The won't automatically get bigger to fit your input;(

Comment: But I can read strings that are more than 2 characters long- console window: 111111
111111
You entered: '11111' and '111111'

Comment: You can, but it's UB.  If the user is manually entering strings, just oversize the array, [1024] or something, and add a max field length in the scanf.

Comment: `malloc` a string and keep `realloc`ing it until you've read it all. And never use `scanf("%s",&s)` without specifying the length.

Comment: I could do that, but i'm surprised there's not a more intuitive way to do this. What if I tried defining x and y like x* and y* and pointers to strings?

Comment: @PSkocik could you link to an example of that? I understand malloc, but I didnt know you could re-allocate after using `malloc`

Comment: @Alex or you could use the `getline` POSIX function which will essentially do it for you. An example is in the [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getline).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no trick to simply get resizing strings.

If the input length is unknown you basically have 2 options:

1. Just limit the lenght of the input and make sure you only write data within the buffer. This is commonly used (for example file names on your hard drive have a limited length)
2. If you really want to dynamically increase your buffer size you need to use dynamic memory management (`malloc`, `calloc`, `free`, `realloc`, ...).

   Try these links to get startet:

   - https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/c-dynamic-memory-allocation
   - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation

Only use number 2 if you really need to (or if you want to learn).

Answer (score 0):

This sample shows how to read one line of user input with unknown length.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// This constant is small so you can easily examine how this code works in debugger
// Buffer increase step
#define BUFSTEP 5

int main()
{
    char *in_str_buf;
    size_t buf_len;
    size_t str_len;

    in_str_buf = NULL;
    buf_len = 0;
    str_len = 0;

    // Read string by parts
    do
    {
        char *in_str_buf_new;

        if ((in_str_buf_new = realloc(in_str_buf, buf_len + BUFSTEP)) == NULL)
        {
            // realloc failed
            free(in_str_buf);
            return -1;
        }
        in_str_buf = in_str_buf_new;
        buf_len += BUFSTEP;
        if (fgets(in_str_buf + str_len, buf_len - str_len, stdin) == NULL)
        {
            // Error or end-of-file condition occured
            if (ferror(stdin))
            {
                free(in_str_buf);
                return -2;
            }
            if (feof(stdin))
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        str_len = strlen(in_str_buf);
    }
    while (str_len && in_str_buf[str_len-1] != '\n');
    // Remove newline for convenience
    in_str_buf[str_len ? str_len - 1 : 0] = '\0';
    printf("Whole string: %s\n", in_str_buf);
    free(in_str_buf);
    return 0;
}
```