# Reading an unknown number of lines with unknown length from stdin

Tags: c, io, stdin, fgets

I'm relatively new to programming in C and am trying to read input from **`stdin`** using **`fgets`**.

To begin with I thought about reading max 50 lines, max 50 characters each, and had something like:

```
int max_length = 50;
char lines[max_length][max_length];
char current_line[max_length];
int idx = 0;

while(fgets(current_line, max_length, stdin) != NULL) {
    strcopy(lines[idx], current_line);
    idx++;
}
```

The snippet above successfully reads the input and stores it into the `lines` array where I can sort and print it.

My question is how do I deal with an unknown number of lines, with an unknown number of characters on each line? (bearing in mind that I will have to sort the lines and print them out).

Comment: use `malloc()`/`realloc()` with a sensible strategy (e.g. double size when you run out) ... check for newline to know whether the line was complete. I think this question is too broad...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to get user input when length is unknown? (C)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46395682/best-way-to-get-user-input-when-length-is-unknown-c)

Comment: Try coding one of these goals first "unknown number of lines, unknown number of characters on each line".  The avoids making this post too broad.

Comment: for unknown number of lines you can use a list to keep them around. For unknown number of chars you might need to run fgets multiple time per line (if the line in the file is longer than max_length) and build your line using malloc/realloc, like in Felix's answer. Just use 'max_length' for increments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there are a number of different variations of this problem already answered, the considerations of how to go about it could use a paragraph. When faced with this problem, the approach is the same regardless of which combination of library or POSIX functions you use to do it.

Essentially, you will dynamically allocate a reasonable number of characters to hold each line. POSIX `getline` will do this for you automatically, using `fgets` you can simply read a fixed buffer full of chars and append them (reallocating storage as necessary) until the `'\n'` character is read (or `EOF` is reached)

If you use `getline`, then you must allocate memory for, and copy the buffer filled. Otherwise, you will overwrite previous lines with each new line read, and when you attempt to `free` each line, you will likely SegFault with *double-free or corruption* as you repeatedly attempt to free the same block of memory.

You can use `strdup` to simply copy the buffer. However, since `strdup` allocates storage, you should validate successful allocation before assigned a pointer to the new block of memory to your collection of lines.

To access each line, you need a pointer to the beginning of each (the block of memory holding each line). A *pointer to pointer to char* is generally used. (e.g. `char **lines;`) Memory allocation is generally handled by allocating some reasonable number of pointers to begin with, keeping track of the number you use, and when you reach the number you have allocated, you `realloc` and double the number of pointers.

As with each read, you need to ***validate*** each memory allocation. (each `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc`) You also need to validate the way your program uses the memory you allocate by running the program through a memory error check program (such as `valgrind` for Linux). They are simple to use, just `valgrind yourexename`.

Putting those pieces together, you can do something similar to the following. The following code will read all lines from the filename provided as the first argument to the program (or from `stdin` by default if no argument is provided) and print the line number and line to `stdout` (keep that in mind if you run it on a 50,000 line file)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NPTR 8

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    size_t ndx = 0,             /* line index */
        nptrs = NPTR,           /* initial number of pointers */
        n = 0;                  /* line alloc size (0, getline decides) */
    ssize_t nchr = 0;           /* return (no. of chars read by getline) */
    char *line = NULL,          /* buffer to read each line */
        **lines = NULL;         /* pointer to pointer to each line */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    /* allocate/validate initial 'nptrs' pointers */
    if (!(lines = calloc (nptrs, sizeof *lines))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: memory exhausted - lines.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* read each line with POSIX getline */
    while ((nchr = getline (&line, &n, fp)) != -1) {
        if (nchr && line[nchr - 1] == '\n') /* check trailing '\n' */
            line[--nchr] = 0;               /* overwrite with nul-char */
        char *buf = strdup (line);          /* allocate/copy line */
        if (!buf) {     /* strdup allocates, so validate */
            fprintf (stderr, "error: strdup allocation failed.\n");
            break;
        }
        lines[ndx++] = buf;     /* assign start address for buf to lines */
        if (ndx == nptrs) {     /* if pointer limit reached, realloc */
            /* always realloc to temporary pointer, to validate success */
            void *tmp = realloc (lines, sizeof *lines * nptrs * 2);
            if (!tmp) {         /* if realloc fails, bail with lines intact */
                fprintf (stderr, "read_input: memory exhausted - realloc.\n");
                break;
            }
            lines = tmp;        /* assign reallocted block to lines */
            /* zero all new memory (optional) */
            memset (lines + nptrs, 0, nptrs * sizeof *lines);
            nptrs *= 2;         /* increment number of allocated pointers */
        }
    }
    free (line);                    /* free memory allocated by getline */

    if (fp != stdin) fclose (fp);   /* close file if not stdin */

    for (size_t i = 0; i < ndx; i++) {
        printf ("line[%3zu] : %s\n", i, lines[i]);
        free (lines[i]);            /* free memory for each line */
    }
    free (lines);                   /* free pointers */

    return 0;
}
```

If you don't have `getline`, or `strdup`, you can easily implement each. There are multiple examples of each on the site. If you cannot find one, let me know. If you have further questions, let me know as well.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the GetString function found [here](https://github.com/CoreData/cs50/blob/master/pset1/cs50.c).

Comment: Totally not an answer but a comment.

Comment: He has to have 20 rep to comment, so he gets a pass, but he understands when he gets 20 rep, comments as answers and not appropriate.